# How to test characters in a string [Assembly]

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm writing a program to search for vowels inside a string, but I'm having trouble testing the individual characters inside the string, I have the basic concept down and I've done this before using C++ and Python, but I don't know how to code it in Assembly.

I'm going to use a switch to add up and test the individual characters, and I know that I need to use a loop to cycle through all the characters, but I'm stuck on actually testing individual characters. (this isn't what I have coded per say but an illustrative example)

```
max_length     dd      40
user_input     resd    max_length
str_len        dw      $ - user_input
GetStr         user_input             ; "I am a boy"
mov            ecx, str_len
```

And this is where I get stuck. How would you test the individual characters of `user_input` ?

In C++ you would have something like `if(user_input[0] = 'Y')`, but how do I translate that type of instruction to assembly (user_input[0])

I understand that it does not work this way in assembly but hopefully this will clear some things up.

```
str_len DW      $ - user_input
max_length      EQU  40

jump_table:   
        DD      case_0
        DD      case_1
        DD      case_2
        DD      case_3
        DD      case_4
        DD      case_5

.UDATA

user_input    resd      max_length


_main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

switch:    
    xor     eax,eax
    xor     ebx,ebx
    PutStr  prompt
    GetStr   user_input
    mov     ecx, [str_len]
    mov     esi, user_input

read:    
    mov     al, byte [esi+ebx]
    or      al, 20h
    cmp     al, 'a'
    je      [jump_table]
    cmp     al, 'e'
    je      [jump_table+4]
    cmp     al, 'i'
    je      [jump_table+8]
    cmp     al, 'o'
    je      [jump_table+12]
    cmp     al, 'u'
    je      [jump_table+16]
    cmp     ecx, 0
    je      [jump_table+20]
    inc     ebx
    jmp     read
```

this is where I am now, as I commented further down I'm getting an error linked to `str_len`

This is all working, I just need to clear the buffer, Thanks!
    str_len         DD       40 
    max_length      EQU      40

```
jump_table:   
        DD      case_0
        DD      case_1
        DD      case_2
        DD      case_3
        DD      case_4
        DD      case_5

.UDATA

user_input    resb      max_length

.CODE

.STARTUP

switch:    
    xor     eax,eax
    xor     ebx,ebx
    xor     esi, esi
    PutStr  prompt
    GetStr  user_input
    mov     ecx, [str_len]
    mov     esi, user_input

read:    
    mov     al, byte [esi+ebx]
    or      al, 20h
    ;PutCh   al
    cmp     al, 'a'
    je      vowel_A
    cmp     al, 'e'
    je      vowel_E
    cmp     al, 'i'
    je      vowel_I
    cmp     al, 'o'
    je      vowel_O
    cmp     al, 'u'
    je      vowel_U
    cmp     ecx, 0
    je      str_end
    inc     ebx
    dec     ecx
    jmp     read
```

Comment: Use `cmp` and then inspect the flags. Or do you need to know how to "load" the characters *per se*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "load", I understand the `cmp` instruction just not how to get at the individual characters

Comment: If you can code this using primitive C++, you're halfway there; the assembly code can be pretty close to a direct transliteration modulo using registers.   If I was deciding if a word contianed a vowel, I'd probably look it up in a table that mapped the character to a boolean,  You'll need to do address arithmetic.

Comment: I need to know how to look directly at the characters in the string, the string might contain more than one vowel and more than one word so this is the path I need to take.

Comment: So, just like C++, you need a string body somewhere in memory, and either an index into the string (added to its base giving the address of a character), or you need a pointer that scans the characters.  Why do you believe "if (user_input[0]=='Y')..." isn't the way it works?

Comment: Okay, you could show me how to code that? What I meant to say is I can't put "if(user_input[0] == 'Y')" directly into my assembly code, I don't know how to translate that into assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mov EAX, [user_input]` would NOT load the string into `eax` but the first 4 bytes of the string.

`user_input` is a pointer.

```
    mov     esi, user_input
    xor     ebx, ebx
SearchForVowel:
    mov     al, byte [esi + ebx]
    test    al, al          ; does al contain a 0
    jz      .Done           ; yes we are done.

    ; check to see if al contains a vowel
    if al does not contain a vowel, jump to NoVowel
    otherwise, increment vowel_counter

.NoVowel:
    inc     ebx
    jmp     SearchForVowel

.Done:
```

No need to store the string length since strings **should** be NULL terminated.

Comment: yes, but Im testing more than just one word, I could be testing a phrase like what I posted in the example. "I am a boy" the phrase has 3 vowels, thats why I was saving the string length

Comment: @Gunner's heart is in the right place, and he's handing you a workable code fragment.  Some people are so used to the C convention that strings are zero terminated, they don't consider that in some cases the string simply has a known length.  Instead of checking for a zero termination character, *you* can replace the check with something that decrements a counter and checks for zero.  You keep acting like you want us to simply write the code for you.

Comment: This piece of code was very useful and I am appreciative of the help I got almost all the way through the code last night, but now im running into an error with establishing the str_len. Since I have to have user_input undefined Im getting an error from str_len cus user_input hasnt been defined yet `expression is not simple or relocatable`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I finished my code up now im just having a problem with clearing the buffer but ill post my final code up top

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be missing is the notion of indexed addressing.

If you don't know this, you really need to back to assembler 101 class or you aren't going
to make much progress. I'm sure you can find a tutorial on the web.

The key ideas are a) registers contain arbitrary values, interpreted either as "just a number" or interpreted as a memory address, b) you can combine such values to fetch/store things to memory. Given that a register (esi) contains a pointer to the base of the string, and the register ecx contains an index into the string, the instruction

```
 mov al,[edx+ecx]
```

will fetch an 8 bit value to the AL register.  The instruction tells the computer to add the values in edx and ecx to form a memory address, and fetch whatever is in that location.  A related instruction:

```
mov  [edx+ecx],al
```

computes the same address, but moves what is in AL into memory.

Unfortunately for you, the x86 CPU has complicated rules about what is allowed in forming a memory address using indexed addressing, and additional rules about how the size of the operand (8,16,32,64) in bits is specified.  This isn't the place for a full tutorial, which is why I suggest you do a bit more homework before proceeding.

Comment: I know what indexed addressing is, and I know what mov does, this was not my question. Storing user_input or `mov EAX, [user_input]` would load the string into the register but knowing how to navigate it once it is in the register is the issue. I can't use ECX because I am loading it with the loop count. To be more specific how would I look at, in particular, the first character in the string?

@Jongware mentioned something about "loading" the characters, but I don't know what he/she is referring to.

Comment: And what other places have you considered putting the character? (This is a trick question.  If you have such a list, you shouldn't be confused.  If you don't have such a list, you don't understand assembler and in particular the x86 architecture well enough).   We don't know what you don't know, but your question is *so* basic that it seems you simply don't understand the machine architecture or what the instructions do.  You seemed to have missed my specific point that "MOV AL,[...]" would fetch (one) 8 bit character.